# Synonym for misspeller

Tags: synonyms

Is there another word for misspeller? I think there ought to be a word for someone who commonly misspells.
Is misspeller even a word?

Comment: Interesting.  If "orthography" is correct spelling, then "______graphy" is incorrect spelling?

Comment: @GEdgar Heterography?

Comment: Yes, "misspeller" is a word. "Heterographer" is a nice one, but I wouldn't trust people to know what I meant. Also note "dyslexic", which is properly a medical diagnosis, but as all mental disorders it can often be used in casual speech for a person who resembles a sufferer (compare "I'm OCD about my boardgames" instead of "I prefer my boardgames in pristine condition").

Answer (score 1):

a **semiliterate** subject/person/individual comes to mind.

It's what I'd call someone who often misspells their words.

> - [**semiliterate**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/semiliterate) (adjective)
>
>   1. barely able to read and write.
>   2. capable of reading but not writing.
>   3. literate but poorly skilled or informed; lacking the proficiency of a literate person.